# Log likelihood of a markov network

Tags: machine-learning, markov-models

I am having trouble understanding the following figure from Coursera class:

[image]

From as far as I understand, the equation corresponds the factor table:

[image]

And therefore the likelihood of a sample data (a = 0, b=0, c=1) for example would be:

[image]

It doesn't look like the graph at any way. Can you please explain the graph for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing probability and likelihood.

You have a probability distribution p, parameterised by \theta, which has support on (A, B, C). The probability distribution is a function of A, B, C for fixed theta. The likelihood function, which is what's being graphed in the figure above, is a function of \theta for *fixed* A, B, C. It's a function which says how probable fixed observations are given different values for the parameters.

In popular usage likelihood and probability are synonymous. In technical use they are not.

With the likelihood/probability issue sorted, that likelihood function is telling you that the joint probability of (A, B, C) is the product of pairwise potentials between all connected pairs, in this case (A, B) and (B, C). I{a^1, b^1) is an indicator function which is 1 when a=1 and b=1 and zero otherwise. \theta_{a^1, b^1} is the parameter corresponding to this outcome.

If I had to guess (I can't see the whole class), I would say there are four \thetas for each pairwise relationship, representing the four possible states (both 1, both 0, or one of each), and we've just dropped the ones where the corresponding indicator function is zero and so the parameters are irrelevant.

Your derivation of the equation is not correct. The form of the MRF basically says add together the parameters corresponding to the correct state of each of the pairs, exponentiate, and normalise. The normalising constant is the sum of the joint probability over all possible configurations.

Comment: You are right. In the calculation of the second equation, I fixed A to 0, B to 0 and C to 1 (which maps to exp(theta2) and then normalized by Z).

Comment: Edited in an answer. I don't know where your theta_1 and theta_2s came from, but I'm pretty sure they're not correct.